# Sharp, salient and opposite cones

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity

I have been reading about star shaped sets and support cones from [this article](https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jca/jca17/jca0840_b.pdf).
Can anyone please help me with examples the difference between a sharp and dull cone.

How come a salient cone has a unique apex? OK if I take the closed positive quadrant $$\{(x,y): x,y\geq 0\},$$ Then it is a sharp cone but no full line through any of its apices is contained in the cone. But it has infinite apices.
Can anyone also explain what is an opposite cone actually. One can also suggest a textbook where this would be explained clearly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The positive orthant has only one apex $(0,0)$. If a sharp cone does not have a unique apex, then the dimension (as an affine subspace) of its summit is $\geq 1$; in particular, contains a line. These (and the ones you posted earlier) are all pretty basic questions about cones, and might be a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/ than MathOverflow.

Comment: Can you tell why an opposite cone is defined as $2a-C$ and not just $-C?$

Comment: That's so that its apex is also $a$ (instead of $-a$).